# Why can I not connect to my Bedrock server from outside?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, technical-issues, networking

I have a Bedrock dedicated server set up in my home NAS, and I can access it just fine on my local network (LAN). I've forwarded ports 19131-19133 through my router to the NAS, and I was able to get a ping from the internet to my server (on port 19132). However, whenever I try to connect externally, it always fails with "Could not connect to world."

I did notice in the logs, whenever it starts up it indicates two different ports:

```
[INFO] IPv4 supported, port: 19132
[INFO] IPv4 supported, port: 39187 // <-- changes every time
```

I've tried looking online for answers, but no joy. For reference, I'm using `marctv/minecraft-bedrock-server` on Docker in my Synology. Not sure if that helps.

*edit: mistyped port range.*

Comment: Don't know if it helps but did you actually opened "*19131-13133*"? that seems.... backward

Comment: Oops, I mistyped. Let me fix that...

Comment: Are you trying to access it from java or another bedrock? if java you may need to create a plugin.